# I was just start learn angular but I can't understand why we not work settimeout() outside the constructor in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
export class ServerComponent implements OnInit { 

    show = false;

    setTimeout(() => {
        this.show = true;
    }, 2000);
  
    constructor(){
    }
    
    ngOnInit(){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you've written outside the constructor is not directly executable in that context because it's not within a method or a lifecycle hook

If you want to execute code after a certain delay, you should place it within a method or a lifecycle hook such as ngOnInit(). For example

```
export class ServerComponent implements OnInit { 
  show = false;
  constructor(){
  }
  ngOnInit(){
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.show = true;
    }, 2000);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put setTimeout or anything that isn't a property of method inside a class definition.

Make sure you understand [Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) properly!

The right way to do this would be to put the `setTimeout` inside your constructor function

Answer (score 0):

Set timeout is basically a prebuilt library function (method) with two parameters.

1. callback function
2. timeout in milliseconds

so what you trying to do is calling a existing library function outside a method or constructor which is not allowed.